# How to install dualboot linux in efi with weird ssd

Tags: linux, ssd, efi

I'm trying to install linux on my efi computer but still not working. I first installed Windows with 120/510 GB disk in EFI mode, and then want to install linux but every single linux just doesn't reconize my SSD (Excepted ubuntu). I think this is because of the name of my SSD (/dev/nvme0n1).

Is this problem will be fixed if I rename /dev/nvme0n1 to /dev/sdb like just a normal disk ? If yes, how to do that ? I tried udev rules but I'm confused with that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No the name is not the REASON, but a RESULT. NVMe is a whole different kind of access interface for PCIe SSDs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express

I don't think Ubuntu is the only distro that supports it. It just happen that the other distros you test has an old kernel or doesn't have the support built into it.

Comment: Greg, support for new chipsets and interfaces tends to trickle down to distributions as those distributions add newer kernels or backport support into their older kernels. Thus, in a few months the support is likely to be much better than it is today. Also, if you're trying an older distribution, try the latest version instead; it may have the necessary support.

Answer (score 0):

What distro are you trying to install ?
For me, on DELL XPS 13, [the Latest archlinux iso](https://www.archlinux.org/download/) successfully recognised my nvme disk.

If you want to install something else, and nvme is not recognised, you'll maybe need to compile the NVME driver. 
When configuring a kernel, it's under `Device Drivers` -> `NVM Express Block Device`. Make sure it has been selected.

[This blog post](http://www.ultrabug.fr/gentoo-linux-on-dell-xps-13-9350/) helped me a lot.